# How to ignore "NullPointerException" in Scala and continue to finish next job for a MapReduce task?

Tags: java, scala, hadoop, mapreduce

I am running a Hadoop-MapReduce job in my Ubuntu VM. In an intermediate stage, I need to check the Hbase database if certain string array exists there, if not found then do nothing and "continue" to the next job, without throwing "NullPointerException".

The Scala code (version 2.11.7) snippet below checks if a row (i.e string array) exists in the Hbase database which was previously created from a MapReduce job. For that, it first uses .readColocationStoreRow() to read that row in the hbase based on rowName input, an then if exists splits it, and then using .contains() it checks if parts of this array (separated by a separator #) exists there. The entire job is run iteratetively.

The problem is when there is no such row (based on rowName input) exists in the hbase database, then I get "NulPointerException" for .split(), which makes sense. My question is how to ignore this "NulPointerException" and continue to the next job?

It's a simple problem, but I am newbie in Scala.

```
  hBaseUtil
   .readColocationStoreRow(rowName = rowName, size = k - 1)
   .split(externalSeperator)
   .contains(sortedInstance.mkString(internalSeprator))
```

Comment: Never "ignore" a NPE, but instead *fix* your code so that it can't happen. This will likely mean not chaining all those method calls together.

Comment: @HovercraftFullOfEels Or using a tool that's explicitly intended to deal with this possibility, like an `Option` type.

Comment: As chrylis said, the best would be to identify which is the operation that returns `null`, wrap its call inside the **Option** _effect / datatype_. And use one of the many combinators that it provides to chain the following calls, like `map` & `flatMap`. Also, if you have a **List** of jobs, which some of them may fail, you can do something like this `val results = jobs.flatMap(job => executeJob(job))`, where `executeJob` returns an **Option**, this way, all _failed_ cases will be ignored.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As mentioned in the comments, wrap the part that might return `null`.

```scala
val row = Option(hBaseUtil.readColocationStoreRow(rowName = rowName, size = k - 1))
val rslt = row.map(_.split(externalSeperator)
                    .contains(sortedInstance.mkString(internalSeprator)))
              .getOrElse(false)
```

Comment: Thanks everyone! I tried answer from @jwvh and my Intellij suggested some modification on that which I accepted. It did the job! Here it is:    
    val row = Option(hBaseUtil.readColocationStoreRow(rowName = rowName, size = k - 1)) 
    row.exists(_.split(externalSeperator)
    .contains(sortedInstance.mkString(internalSeprator)))